# using two replace statements in a loop pandas inplace true

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dictionary of google sheets that I turn into data sets

```
classes_dict_ms = {'Missing students Math': 'missing_students_math_8,
'Missing students ENG': 'missing_students_eng_8'}
```

They are read from google sheets so they have some #N/A and #REF and I am trying to get rid of them:

```
for key, val in sheet_dict.items():
  rows = val.get_all_values() #needed to read all the data in
  vars()["df_" + key] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
  vars()["df_" + key].replace("#REF!", pd.NA, inplace=True) #replaces #REFs with nulls
  vars()["df_" + key].replace("#N/A", pd.NA, inplace=True) #replaces #NA with nulls
  vars()["df_" + key].dropna(subset = ["Last name"], inplace=True) #drops rows with a null last name
```

It will work for the first data set but not the second? and if I eliminate the #ref it will work both? not sure what is going on here

my second attempt:

```
df_dict_ms = {} #make blank dictionary

for key, val in sheet_dict_ms.items():
  # read the data and create a dataframe df
  rows = val.get_all_values() #needed to read all the data in
  vars()["df_" + key] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows[1:], columns=rows[0]) #starts the data set at row 2 (since there is a title)

  #modify dataframe
  vars()["df_" + key].replace("#REF!", pd.NA, inplace=True) #replaces #REFs with nulls
  vars()["df_" + key].replace("#N/A", pd.NA, inplace=True) #replaces #NA with nulls
  vars()["df_" + key].dropna(subset = ["Last Name"], inplace=True) #drops rows with a null last name 
  df_dict_ms["df_" + key] =  vars()["df_" + key] #add to dictionary
```

my third attempt:

```
new_data = {} #make blank dictionary

for key, val in sheet_dict_ms.items():
  # read the data and create a dataframe df
  rows = val.get_all_values() #needed to read all the data in
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])

  # modify your data frame
  df.replace("#REF!", pd.NA, inplace=True) #replaces #REFs with nulls
  df.replace("#N/A", pd.NA, inplace=True) #replaces #NA with nulls
  df.dropna(subset = ["Last Stored"], inplace=True) #drops rows with a nu

  # store the modified dataframe into you empty dictionary
  new_data[key] = df
new_data
```

Answer (score 0):

To mimic the reading of data I do

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

file_as_str = """
A,B,C,D,E
aaaa, bbbb,#REF!,ccc,#N/A
dddd,#REF!, #N/A,eeee,ffff
#REF!,gggg,#N/A,hhhh,iiii
"""
# an empty dictionary to store your dataframes
sheet_dict = {}
for cnt in range(2):
    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_as_str))
    sheet_dict[f"key_{cnt}"] = data
```

You can pretty print the 2 data frames with

```
for k, df in sheet_dict.items():
    print(f"before df {k}")
    print(df.to_markdown())
```

Resulting in:

```
before df key_0
|    | A     | B     | C     | D    | E    |
|---:|:------|:------|:------|:-----|:-----|
|  0 | aaaa  | bbbb  | #REF! | ccc  | nan  |
|  1 | dddd  | #REF! | #N/A  | eeee | ffff |
|  2 | #REF! | gggg  | nan   | hhhh | iiii |
before df key_1
|    | A     | B     | C     | D    | E    |
|---:|:------|:------|:------|:-----|:-----|
|  0 | aaaa  | bbbb  | #REF! | ccc  | nan  |
|  1 | dddd  | #REF! | #N/A  | eeee | ffff |
|  2 | #REF! | gggg  | nan   | hhhh | iiii |
```

Notice that the #N/A on the first line of the fake file already has been transformed to a nan by read_csv. In the second line I have added a space before #N/A in order to avoid transformation to nan

Using var() for dynamic variabele names is not a good idea; it is hard to debug. If you need variabele names, use dicts.
Filtering the data of the dict can be done as:

```
new_data = {}
for key, df in sheet_dict.items():
    # modify your data frame
    df.replace("\s*#REF!", "NA", regex=True, inplace=True)
    df.replace("\s*#N/A", "NA", regex=True, inplace=True)
    df.dropna(subset=["E"], how='any', inplace=True)

    # store the modified dataframe into you empty dictionary
    new_data[key] = df
```

Now, we can show the new result with:

```
for k, df in new_data.items():
    print(f"after df {k}")
    print(df.to_markdown())
```

The result looks like:

```
after df key_0
|    | A    | B    | C   | D    | E    |
|---:|:-----|:-----|:----|:-----|:-----|
|  1 | dddd | NA   | NA  | eeee | ffff |
|  2 | NA   | gggg | nan | hhhh | iiii |
after df key_1
|    | A    | B    | C   | D    | E    |
|---:|:-----|:-----|:----|:-----|:-----|
|  1 | dddd | NA   | NA  | eeee | ffff |
|  2 | NA   | gggg | nan | hhhh | iiii |
```

So the problem is not with the inplace modification, but with your replace expression. I noticed what a field with a leading space does not match your replace pattern. Therefore, use regex=True as argument and add \s* (for potential leading spaces). Now you get what you expect

Comment: this is essentially what I am doing right? codes are direct actions on the dataframes.

I guess I mispoke at first, I have a google sheet that I turn into dataframes, and then I preform the action. I have updated the code as such

Comment: No, because in your case the dataframe read into 'rows' (i.e. in a new allocated data frame) and than you modify 'rows', but this is not applied to the dataframe in your dictionary. I will modify my answer to show how you could this

Comment: so I need to drop the 'vars()["df_" + key]' statement? I updated my code keeping that since I need to dynamically name my dataframes. With what you suggested, it still only modifies the first dataframe and not the second. I can't simply put df right? because then both dataframes in the dictionary will have the same name but a different key.

Comment: actually I tried the exact way you listed then I printed the dictionary new_data and the second dataframe still didn't have the #N/A replaced

Comment: The problem was your N/A replace statement. I have made a MWE. should work now